# Razor Regex Replace All But Numbers and One Dash Between

Tags: regex, razor, model-view-controller

I want to include a number followed by one dash and then another number.

@Regex.Replace(@a, @"[^0-9+-]", "")

... but that includes all dashes.

Replace a string like this:

```
Text (Characters!+-) 11-20 text-dashes-after-not counted
```

to become just:

```
11-20
```

http://regexr.com/3b0k7

The problem is that it allows any number of dashes, and I only want to include one if it is between the numbers -- with any number of spaces between the first number, the dash, and the second number.

Comment: Why not use `Regex.Match` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
@Regex.Replace(@a, @"^.*?\b(\d+\s*-\s*\d+)\b.*", "$1")
```

Comment: This works, but what is your opinion on the difference between Regex.Replace and Regex.Match?

Comment: `Replace` will give your desired text in one step but `match` will return you an array that you will have to evaluate later.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically like Amit's suggestion, but you can capture it using a named group as well.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<test>\d+-\d+)");

Match match = regex.Match(sample);

if (match.Success)
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["test"].Value);
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach, but I am looking for something more compact and concise. Thanks

Comment: I chose @anubhava solution because it can be contained nicely in one step.